# Developer Console Syntax highlighting messed up when included script tag in Visualforce

Tags: visualforce, developer-console

When script tag is not there

[image]

When script tag is there

[image]

Can anyone point out what is going wrong there?

Comment: Try putting the closing script tag on a new line, sometimes that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, @Kasper!!

Putting the closing script tag on a new line helped me.